# Compare columns in two pandas dataframe to and spit out differences

Tags: python, csv, pandas, twitter, dataframe

I have two csv files, all containing tweets posted on day1 and day2. I want to compare the authors of the tweets to discover new users.

day1.csv looks like this:

```
authorID
451223
120346
122355
787456
```

day2.csv looks like this:

```
authorID
451223
025660
122355
022000
```

Using day1.csv as the pivot... I want to compare the author IDs.. any new author (i.e. an author in day2.csv but not in day1.csv), I output the author's ID. Please how can i do this in python 3.XX

Answer (score 1):

If you have both CSV files loaded as iterables (`f.readlines()`?) then you can simply use a set difference to return a new set with elements of day2.csv that are not in day1.csv:

```
>>> day1 = ['authorID',451223,120346,122355,787456]
>>> day2 = ['authorID',451223,025660,122355,022000]
>>> set(day2) - set(day1)
set([11184, 9216])
```

or

```
>>> set(day2).difference(day1)
set([11184, 9216])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.DataFrame({'authorID':['12','34','56']})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'authorID':['12','56','78','97']})
original_users=set(df1[['authorID']].values.reshape(-1))
for i in df2[['authorID']].values.reshape(-1):
    if i not in original_users:
        print(i)
```

Then `df1` is

```
    u
0   12
1   34
2   56
```

and `df2` is

```
    u
0   12
1   56
2   78
3   97
```

The output is

```
78
97
```

Note that `df1[['authorID']].values.reshape(-1)` enables you to transform the column to a list over which you can iterate. For this particular example,
`df1[['authorID']].values.reshape(-1)` is `array(['12', '34', '56'], dtype=object)`. The transformation of this array to a `set` was done to improve the complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to compare the difference between the two sets of `authorID`s:

```
>>> old = {'451223', '120346', '122355', '787456'}
>>> new = {'451223', '025660', '122355', '022000'}
>>> {x for x in new if x not in old}
{'025660', '022000'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `day1` and `day2` are dataframes... use `merge` with the `indicator` parameter set to `True`

```
day1.merge(day2, 'outer', indicator=True).query('_merge != "both"')

   authorID      _merge
1    120346   left_only
3    787456   left_only
4     25660  right_only
5     22000  right_only
```